# inside ring sprite kit

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit, game-physics

I'm building game with SpriteKit in swift. I have ring image

[image]

I want to fly object through ring and if object touches the ring's sides the game ends.
So I want to make ring physical object which has a gap inside.

```
let gap = SKNode()
gap.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)  + self.frame.size.width, y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + ringOffset)
gap.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(ring.size.width, gapHeight))
gap.runAction(moveAndRemoveRings)
gap.physicsBody?.dynamic = true

movingObjects.addChild(gap)
```

I have this code if it helps you

Comment: It is unclear what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

If this ring is a png texture on that Sprite, just use your texture as physicsBody.